# Checkered pattern on itunes?

Tags: itunes, video

my friend and I who live in different states wanted to watch a movie. We both rented out a movie on iTunes together. We used Skype to screen share, but on my friend's end she sees a checkered pattern. Why is that? Is there any way around it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd assume that's some kind of DRM (Digital Rights Management) protection. I recall from the early days, when Macs still had optical drives and a DVD player app, that if you tried to take a screenshot while the DVD player was visible, even as you saw a frame of the movie there, it came out black in the screenshot. So I guess these kinds of countermeasures go a long way and Apple has no intention of removing them.

As for a way around it, I suppose site policy frowns upon discussing what is effectively piracy (even if you try to argue this might be fair use, which I might actually concede).

Comment: Oh! That makes sense! I had no idea! In that case, yeah It's best not find a way around it. Thanks so much!